# How do I tell Python to combine every row in a column and return the ones that add up to zero?

Tags: python, dataframe, combinations

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Price 
-2000
-1750
-1200
-1000
-500
0
500
1000
1200
1750
2000
```

It is important for me to know which rows have the same value (in absolute terms) or which combinations of rows add up to zero (such as -1200 + 1200 = 0 so that would be one successful combination).

I've always had problems comparing multiple rows in the same column so I thought you might be able to help me! Thanks a lot in advance.

Ps: Just a quick thank you in general for how much this community supports learning and newbies. You guys probably do more for developing coding knowledge than anywhere else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `groupby`

```
df['abs_price'] = df['Price'].apply(abs)
gp = df.groupby('abs_price')
gp.groups
```

Out:

```
{0: Int64Index([5], dtype='int64'),
 500: Int64Index([4, 6], dtype='int64'),
 1000: Int64Index([3, 7], dtype='int64'),
 1200: Int64Index([2, 8], dtype='int64'),
 1750: Int64Index([1, 9], dtype='int64'),
 2000: Int64Index([0, 10], dtype='int64')}
```

Just to extend on this, If you didn't want two positive number to be grouped together, you could find all the pairs or rows that add up to 0 quite easily:

```
import itertools

zero_combinations = []
for index_combo in itertools.combinations(df.index, 2):
    if df.iloc[list(index_combo),]['price'].sum() == 0:
        zero_combinations.append(index_combo)
print(zero_combinations)

Out: [(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]
```

Comment: Worth noting that although this works for the dataset posted, it would also group two identical positive values together if they exist. Might not be an issue as it's not clear if two such rows could exist in OP's dataset but thought I should mention.

Comment: @thesilkworm makes a good point, I wrote this answer considering the OP said they wanted to know which rows have the same value in absolute terms, without considering that the OP may not wish to group two of the same positive number